# How can I inject multiple lines with Devel::Declare?

Tags: perl

I want to use [`Devel::Declare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare) to inject multiple lines of Perl code.  However, `Devel::Declare::set_linestr()` cannot deal with multiple lines.

Normally I would join multiple statements together as a single line.  These statements must be on separate lines to preserve their line numbers for error reporting purposes.  This is to solve [this bug in Method::Signatures](https://github.com/evalEmpire/method-signatures/issues/104) and [this related bug](https://github.com/evalEmpire/method-signatures/issues/106).  I'm open to alternative solutions.

For example, Method::Signatures currently turns this code...

```
use Method::Signatures;

func hello(
    $who = "World",
    $greeting = get_greeting($who)
) {
    die "$greeting, $who";
}
```

...into this...

```
func  \&hello; sub hello  { BEGIN { Method::Signatures->inject_scope('') }; my $who = (@_ > 0) ? ($_[0]) : ( get_greeting($who)); my $greeting = (@_ > 1) ? ($_[1]) : ( "Hello"); Method::Signatures->too_many_args_error(2) if @_ > 2;
    die "$greeting, $who";
}
```

`die $who` then reports line 4 instead of line 7.

I would like it to instead be this (or perhaps something involving `#line`).

```
func  \&hello; sub hello  { BEGIN { Method::Signatures->inject_scope('') };
    my $who = (@_ > 0) ? ($_[0]) : ( "World");
    my $greeting = (@_ > 1) ? ($_[1]) : ( get_greeting($who));
    Method::Signatures->too_many_args_error(2) if @_ > 2;
    die "$greeting, $who";
}
```

Not only does this faithfully reproduce the line numbers, should `get_greeting` croak it will report having been called from the correct line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your own answer, the following works:

```
sub __empty() { '' }

sub parse_proto {
    my $self = shift;
    return q[print __LINE__."\n"; Foo::__empty(
);print __LINE__."\n"; Foo::__empty(
);print __LINE__."\n";];
}
```

But introduces unacceptable overhead because the `__empty()` function must be called for every parameter. The overhead can be eliminated by calling `__empty()` conditionally using a condition which will never evaluate to true.

```
sub __empty() { '' }

sub parse_proto {
    my $self = shift;
    return q[print __LINE__."\n"; 0 and Foo::__empty(
);print __LINE__."\n"; 0 and Foo::__empty(
);print __LINE__."\n";];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a way to do it, but it's hacky and slow.

I noticed you could inject strings with literal newlines in them and they'd work.  I reckon the parser knows enough to keep going past a newline in a string.  I figured one can exploit that to trick the parser to keep going.

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.12;

use parent "Devel::Declare::MethodInstaller::Simple";

sub import {
    my $class = shift;
    my $caller = caller;

    $class->install_methodhandler(
        into            => $caller,
        name            => 'method'
    );
}

sub parse_proto {
    my $self = shift;
    return q[print __LINE__."\n"; my $__empty = q{
};print __LINE__."\n"; $__empty = q{
};print __LINE__."\n";];
}

1;
```

And it works... except `__LINE__` doesn't get incremented.  Glitch in the Perl parser?  I tried a regex with a newline in it, that didn't increment the line either.

But a subroutine does work!

```
sub __empty() { '' }

sub parse_proto {
    my $self = shift;
    return q[print __LINE__."\n"; Foo::__empty(
);print __LINE__."\n"; Foo::__empty(
);print __LINE__."\n";];
}
```

And it's a constant subroutine call, Perl should optimize it out, right?  Alas, no.  It seems the newline in the call fools the optimizer.  On the upside, this avoids a "Useless use of a constant in void context" warning.  On the down side, it introduces a subroutine call for each parameter and that's an unacceptable amount of overhead to add to every subroutine call.

Maybe someone else can come up with a clever way to squeak a newline into Perl syntax?

Comment: Have you tried changing `Foo::__empty()` to `() and Foo::__empty()`?

Comment: @tobyink That works!  Even better is `Foo::__empty() if 0` which is optimized away.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. I would have expected `()` to be optimized away the same as `0`, but trying it out with B::Deparse, it seems not!